# Yii2 create multilingual site for ajax search fields

Tags: php, yii2, frameworks, multilingual

I'm using `Yii2` and I want to create a web application with the ability to perform fast searches.
For example, when I type characters in a textbox, results displayed.
It's easy with `ajax` when we have only one language but how about in ***multilingual*** mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First set up multi language for your site there is [doc](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/tutorial-i18n) for this.

Best way of auto support multi language for your site is using cookies variable for language. You can set up language cookies from any action as

```
   public function actionLanguage()
{
    if (isset($_POST['lang'])) {
        $language = $_POST['lang'];

        if (($langaugeModel = \app\models\Langauge::findOne(['name' => $language])) !== null) {
            $varLang = [
                    'id' => $langaugeModel->id,
                    'name' => $langaugeModel->name,
                    'iso1' => $langaugeModel->iso1,
                    'iso2' => $langaugeModel->iso2
                ];
            $cookies = new Cookie([
                'name' => 'lang',
                'value' => json_encode($varLang),
            ]);
            yii::$app->getResponse()->getCookies()->add($cookies);
            return $this->goBack((!empty(Yii::$app->request->referrer) ? Yii::$app->request->referrer : null));
        } else {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException('The requested langauge does not exist.');
        }

    } else {
            return $this->goBack((!empty(Yii::$app->request->referrer) ? Yii::$app->request->referrer : null));
    }
}
```

Here what I did was i placed all the language support of site in database and generate necessary cookies variable and placed it on client browser.

Next set up be before request event of your yii2 site in config/web.php file as

```
 'as beforeRequest' => [
   'class' => 'app\components\MyBehavior',
],
```

then create components\Mybehaviou.php file and place this code

```
  namespace app\components;
  use yii;
  use yii\base\Behavior;
  class MyBehavior extends Behavior
   {
     public function events(){
       return [
           \yii\web\Application::EVENT_BEFORE_REQUEST => 'myBehavior',
         ];
       }
    public function myBehavior(){
    if (\yii::$app->getRequest()->getCookies()->has('lang')) {
        $langIso = 'sdn';
        \yii::$app->language = $langIso;
        $langaugeVar = \yii::$app->getRequest()->getCookies()->getValue('lang');

        $langauge = json_decode($langaugeVar);
        $langIso = $langauge->iso2;

        \yii::$app->language = $langIso;

    }
  }
}
```

This create your site language which depends on client because it depends on cookies of client.

Then create your search controller according to site language(\yii::$app->language)

for ajax search you can use [select2](http://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/select2) Widget. you can find demo and configuration on this [link](http://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/select2)